# Custom dialog box to show video camera app

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, android-alertdialog, video-capture

I have an intent that can handle my camera app and directly go to the recording option.
What i want is that i can choose my own video camera app.

Here is my code to record a video.

```
private void recordVideo() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);

    // set video quality
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file
                                                        // name

    // start the video capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```